# Csv parsing program & how to flatten multiple lists into single list

Tags: list, csv, urlparse

Ive been working on a small program that I need to do the following:

Take a csv file 'domains_prices.csv' with a column of domains and then a price for each e.g.:

```
http://www.example1.com,$20
http://www.example2.net,$30
```

and so on

and then a second file 'orders_list.csv' which is just a single column of blog post urls from the same domains listed in the 1st file e.g.:

```
http://www.exmaple2.net/blog-post-1
http://www.example1.com/some-article
http://www.exmaple3.net/blog-post-feb-19
```

and so on

I need to check the full urls from the orders_list against the domains in the 1st file and check what the price is of a blog post on that domain and then output all the blog post urls into a new file with the price for each e.g.:

```
http://www.example2.net/blog-post-1, $20
```

and then there would be a total amount at the end of the output file.

My plan was to create a dict for domains_prices with k,v as domain & price and then have all the urls from orders_list in a list and then compare the elements of that list against the prices in the dict.

This is my code, Im stuck towards the end, I have parsed_orders_list and it seems to be returning all the urls as individual lists so Im thinking I should put all those urls into a single list?

Also the final commented out code at the end is the operation I intend to do once I have the correct list of urls to compare them against the k, v of the dict, Im not sure if thats correct too though.

Please note this is also my first every full python program Ive created from scratch so if its horrendous then thats why :)

```
import csv
from urlparse import urlparse

#get the csv file with all domains and prices in
reader = csv.reader(open("domains_prices.csv", 'r'))

#get all the completed blog post urls
reader2 = csv.reader(open('orders_list.csv', 'r'))

domains_prices={}


orders_list = []




for row in reader2:
    #put the blog post urls into a list
    orders_list.append(','.join(row))


for domain, price in reader:
    #strip the domains
    domain = domain.replace('http://', '').replace('/','')

    #insert the domains and prices into the dictionary
    domains_prices[domain] = price


for i in orders_list:
    #iterate over the blog post urls orders_list and
    #then parse them with urlparse
    data = urlparse(i)

    #use netloc to get just the domain from each blog post url
    parsed_orders =  data.netloc


    parsed_orders_list = parsed_orders.split()


    print parsed_orders_list


"""
for k in parsed_orders:
    if k in domains_prices:
        print k, domains_prices[k]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of someone else Ive figured it out, made the following changes to the 'for i in orders_list' section

```
parsed_orders = []

for i in orders_list:
#iterate over the blog post urls orders_list and
#then parse them with urlparse
data = urlparse(i)

#use netloc to get just the domain from each blog post url then put each netloc url into a list
parsed_orders.append(data.netloc)


#print parsed_orders - to check that Im getting a list of netloc urls back

#Iterate over the list of urls and dict of domains and prices to match them up
for k in parsed_orders:
    if k in domains_prices:
        print k, domains_prices[k]
```